# Weka Attribute Selection

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm trying to perform Attribute Selection in Weka. I would like to use InfoGainAttributeEval as an evaluator, because I read that it is equivalent to mutual information, and Ranker as a search method. Should I perform attribute selection to both training and test set? Also, how can I choose the correct value for the N parameter?

Thanks a lot for your time,

Nadia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying attribute selection separately on the train and test might result in a selection of different attributes, thereby making them incompatible. Thus to make sure that both sets have the same attributes you need to apply attribute selection on your whole dataset. Once you have selected the most useful attributes you split your data into a train and test set.

As to which value of `-N` to use, I would use your total amount of attributes. This will result in a ranked list of all your attributes and you can evaluate the different scores of all attributes yourself. You might then spot a clear threshold separating the attributes holding any useful information to train a classifier from attributes which add nothing. I would then set this threshold using the `-T` option.

Comment: Hello @Sicco! I guess that batch filtering is equivalent to your method for making training and test set compatible. Your suggestions about -N and -T parameters helped me clarify the issue and I am about to try them in Weka. Thanks a lot for the information and sorry for the delayed answer!

Comment: won't choosing attributes this way overfit?

Comment: @fiacobelli It depends on how strict you set the threshold. If you only take the best performing attribute and disregard the rest that overfitting is more likely indeed. My intended advice was to take as many attributes which seem to hold some interesting data and remove the attributes which clearly lack valuable information. I made this more clear in my answer.

Comment: @Sicco Can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119712/attribute-selection-in-weka-work-gave-weird-result